# How do I keep DIVs on the same line when using a JQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, uislider

I want to have an image, a jQuery slider, and another image on the same line.  From what I've read and asked, I could normally do this with the styles

```
#sliderScaleDiv {
        display: inline;
}

#halo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
}

#skull {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

in which my DIVs were set up as such

```
<div id="sliderScaleDiv">
<div id="halo">
            <img width="75" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/c/1/B/r/q/angel-halo-with-wings.svg" alt="Angel halo" />
        </div>
<div class="slider"></div>
        <div id="skull">
            <img width="75" src="https://temporarytattoos.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x560/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/s/k/skull-and-crossbones-temporary-tattoos_1601.jpg" alt="Skull" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

but in the Fiddle I created -- http://jsfiddle.net/u72596ta/4/ , this isn't happening.  I'm wondering if its because of the slider component.  It gets initialized after the page loads.  Is there a way I can keep everything on the same line and still have my functional slider?

Comment: you mean that the images should stick in front and back of the drag handle on the slider line and move along when you drag the handle on the slider

Comment: Not even that complicated -- just that one image should appear to the left and the other to the right.  They can remain exactly where they are while the person is interacting with the slider.

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide width to the parent `container` and then to the `slider` too along with 
`display:inline-block` see below.

**EDIT**

You can use fluid width for the center div with fixed width for the divs on the left(`#halo`) and right(`#skull`) so that the middle div(`.fluid`) expands automatically according to the available space, you can use `display: table` for the parent container and `display:table-cell` for the children divs.

```js
(function($) {

  "use strict";

  var extensionMethods = {





    // pips

    pips: function(settings) {

      var slider = this,
        i, j, p,
        collection = "",
        mousedownHandlers,
        min = slider._valueMin(),
        max = slider._valueMax(),
        pips = (max - min) / slider.options.step,
        $handles = slider.element.find(".ui-slider-handle"),
        $pips;

      var options = {

        first: "label",
        /* "label", "pip", false */

        last: "label",
        /* "label", "pip", false */

        rest: "pip",
        /* "label", "pip", false */

        labels: false,
        /* [array], { first: "string", rest: [array], last: "string" }, false */

        prefix: "",
        /* "", string */

        suffix: "",
        /* "", string */

        step: (pips > 100) ? Math.floor(pips * 0.05) : 1,
        /* number */

        formatLabel: function(value) {
          return this.prefix + value + this.suffix;
        }
        /* function
            must return a value to display in the pip labels */

      };

      if ($.type(settings) === "object" || $.type(settings) === "undefined") {

        $.extend(options, settings);
        slider.element.data("pips-options", options);

      } else {

        if (settings === "destroy") {

          destroy();

        } else if (settings === "refresh") {

          slider.element.slider("pips", slider.element.data("pips-options"));

        }

        return;

      }


      // we don't want the step ever to be a floating point or negative
      // (or 0 actually, so we'll set it to 1 in that case).
      slider.options.pipStep = Math.abs(Math.round(options.step)) || 1;

      // get rid of all pips that might already exist.
      slider.element
        .off(".selectPip")
        .addClass("ui-slider-pips")
        .find(".ui-slider-pip")
        .remove();

      // small object with functions for marking pips as selected.

      var selectPip = {

        single: function(value) {

          this.resetClasses();

          $pips
            .filter(".ui-slider-pip-" + this.classLabel(value))
            .addClass("ui-slider-pip-selected");

          if (slider.options.range) {

            $pips.each(function(k, v) {

              var pipVal = $(v).children(".ui-slider-label").data("value");

              if ((slider.options.range === "min" && pipVal < value) ||
                (slider.options.range === "max" && pipVal > value)) {

                $(v).addClass("ui-slider-pip-inrange");

              }

            });

          }

        },

        range: function(values) {

          this.resetClasses();

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            $pips
              .filter(".ui-slider-pip-" + this.classLabel(values[i]))
              .addClass("ui-slider-pip-selected-" + (i + 1));

          }

          if (slider.options.range) {

            $pips.each(function(k, v) {

              var pipVal = $(v).children(".ui-slider-label").data("value");

              if (pipVal > values[0] && pipVal < values[1]) {

                $(v).addClass("ui-slider-pip-inrange");

              }

            });

          }

        },

        classLabel: function(value) {

          return value.toString().replace(".", "-");

        },

        resetClasses: function() {

          var regex = /(^|\s*)(ui-slider-pip-selected|ui-slider-pip-inrange)(-{1,2}\d+|\s|$)/gi;

          $pips.removeClass(function(index, css) {
            return (css.match(regex) || []).join(" ");
          });

        }

      };

      function getClosestHandle(val) {

        var h, k,
          sliderVals,
          comparedVals,
          closestVal,
          tempHandles = [],
          closestHandle = 0;

        if (slider.values() && slider.values().length) {

          // get the current values of the slider handles
          sliderVals = slider.values();

          // find the offset value from the `val` for each
          // handle, and store it in a new array
          comparedVals = $.map(sliderVals, function(v) {
            return Math.abs(v - val);
          });

          // figure out the closest handles to the value
          closestVal = Math.min.apply(Math, comparedVals);

          // if a comparedVal is the closestVal, then
          // set the value accordingly, and set the closest handle.
          for (h = 0; h < comparedVals.length; h++) {
            if (comparedVals[h] === closestVal) {
              tempHandles.push(h);
            }
          }

          // set the closest handle to the first handle in array,
          // just incase we have no _lastChangedValue to compare to.
          closestHandle = tempHandles[0];

          // now we want to find out if any of the closest handles were
          // the last changed handle, if so we specify that handle to change
          for (k = 0; k < tempHandles.length; k++) {
            if (slider._lastChangedValue === tempHandles[k]) {
              closestHandle = tempHandles[k];
            }
          }

          if (slider.options.range && tempHandles.length === 2) {

            if (val > sliderVals[1]) {

              closestHandle = tempHandles[1];

            } else if (val < sliderVals[0]) {

              closestHandle = tempHandles[0];

            }

          }

        }

        return closestHandle;

      }

      function destroy() {

        slider.element
          .off(".selectPip")
          .on("mousedown.slider", slider.element.data("mousedown-original"))
          .removeClass("ui-slider-pips")
          .find(".ui-slider-pip")
          .remove();

      }

      // when we click on a label, we want to make sure the
      // slider's handle actually goes to that label!
      // so we check all the handles and see which one is closest
      // to the label we clicked. If 2 handles are equidistant then
      // we move both of them. We also want to trigger focus on the
      // handle.

      // without this method the label is just treated like a part
      // of the slider and there's no accuracy in the selected value

      function labelClick(label, e) {

        if (slider.option("disabled")) {
          return;
        }

        var val = $(label).data("value"),
          indexToChange = getClosestHandle(val);

        if (slider.values() && slider.values().length) {

          slider.options.values[indexToChange] = slider._trimAlignValue(val);

        } else {

          slider.options.value = slider._trimAlignValue(val);

        }

        slider._refreshValue();
        slider._change(e, indexToChange);

      }

      // method for creating a pip. We loop this for creating all
      // the pips.

      function createPip(which) {

        var label,
          percent,
          number = which,
          classes = "ui-slider-pip",
          css = "",
          value = slider.value(),
          values = slider.values(),
          labelValue,
          classLabel,
          labelIndex;

        if (which === "first") {

          number = 0;

        } else if (which === "last") {

          number = pips;

        }

        // labelValue is the actual value of the pip based on the min/step
        labelValue = min + (slider.options.step * number);

        // classLabel replaces any decimals with hyphens
        classLabel = labelValue.toString().replace(".", "-");

        // get the index needed for selecting labels out of the array
        labelIndex = (number + min) - min;

        // we need to set the human-readable label to either the
        // corresponding element in the array, or the appropriate
        // item in the object... or an empty string.

        if ($.type(options.labels) === "array") {

          label = options.labels[labelIndex] || "";

        } else if ($.type(options.labels) === "object") {

          if (which === "first") {

            // set first label
            label = options.labels.first || "";

          } else if (which === "last") {

            // set last label
            label = options.labels.last || "";

          } else if ($.type(options.labels.rest) === "array") {

            // set other labels, but our index should start at -1
            // because of the first pip.
            label = options.labels.rest[labelIndex - 1] || "";

          } else {

            // urrggh, the options must be f**ked, just show nothing.
            label = labelValue;

          }

        } else {

          label = labelValue;

        }




        if (which === "first") {

          // first Pip on the Slider
          percent = "0%";

          classes += " ui-slider-pip-first";
          classes += (options.first === "label") ? " ui-slider-pip-label" : "";
          classes += (options.first === false) ? " ui-slider-pip-hide" : "";

        } else if (which === "last") {

          // last Pip on the Slider
          percent = "100%";

          classes += " ui-slider-pip-last";
          classes += (options.last === "label") ? " ui-slider-pip-label" : "";
          classes += (options.last === false) ? " ui-slider-pip-hide" : "";

        } else {

          // all other Pips
          percent = ((100 / pips) * which).toFixed(4) + "%";

          classes += (options.rest === "label") ? " ui-slider-pip-label" : "";
          classes += (options.rest === false) ? " ui-slider-pip-hide" : "";

        }

        classes += " ui-slider-pip-" + classLabel;


        // add classes for the initial-selected values.
        if (values && values.length) {

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            if (labelValue === values[i]) {

              classes += " ui-slider-pip-initial-" + (i + 1);
              classes += " ui-slider-pip-selected-" + (i + 1);

            }

          }

          if (slider.options.range) {

            if (labelValue > values[0] &&
              labelValue < values[1]) {

              classes += " ui-slider-pip-inrange";

            }

          }

        } else {

          if (labelValue === value) {

            classes += " ui-slider-pip-initial";
            classes += " ui-slider-pip-selected";

          }

          if (slider.options.range) {

            if ((slider.options.range === "min" && labelValue < value) ||
              (slider.options.range === "max" && labelValue > value)) {

              classes += " ui-slider-pip-inrange";

            }

          }

        }



        css = (slider.options.orientation === "horizontal") ?
          "left: " + percent :
          "bottom: " + percent;


        // add this current pip to the collection
        return "<span class=\"" + classes + "\" style=\"" + css + "\">" +
          "<span class=\"ui-slider-line\"></span>" +
          "<span class=\"ui-slider-label\" data-value=\"" +
          labelValue + "\">" + options.formatLabel(label) + "</span>" +
          "</span>";

      }

      // create our first pip
      collection += createPip("first");

      // for every stop in the slider where we need a pip; create one.
      for (p = slider.options.pipStep; p < pips; p += slider.options.pipStep) {
        collection += createPip(p);
      }

      // create our last pip
      collection += createPip("last");

      // append the collection of pips.
      slider.element.append(collection);

      // store the pips for setting classes later.
      $pips = slider.element.find(".ui-slider-pip");



      // store the mousedown handlers for later, just in case we reset
      // the slider, the handler would be lost!

      if ($._data(slider.element.get(0), "events").mousedown &&
        $._data(slider.element.get(0), "events").mousedown.length) {

        mousedownHandlers = $._data(slider.element.get(0), "events").mousedown;

      } else {

        mousedownHandlers = slider.element.data("mousedown-handlers");

      }

      slider.element.data("mousedown-handlers", mousedownHandlers.slice());

      // loop through all the mousedown handlers on the slider,
      // and store the original namespaced (.slider) event handler so
      // we can trigger it later.
      for (j = 0; j < mousedownHandlers.length; j++) {
        if (mousedownHandlers[j].namespace === "slider") {
          slider.element.data("mousedown-original", mousedownHandlers[j].handler);
        }
      }

      // unbind the mousedown.slider event, because it interferes with
      // the labelClick() method (stops smooth animation), and decide
      // if we want to trigger the original event based on which element
      // was clicked.
      slider.element
        .off("mousedown.slider")
        .on("mousedown.selectPip", function(e) {

          var $target = $(e.target),
            closest = getClosestHandle($target.data("value")),
            $handle = $handles.eq(closest);

          $handle.addClass("ui-state-active");

          if ($target.is(".ui-slider-label")) {

            labelClick($target, e);

            slider.element
              .one("mouseup.selectPip", function() {

                $handle
                  .removeClass("ui-state-active")
                  .focus();

              });

          } else {

            var originalMousedown = slider.element.data("mousedown-original");
            originalMousedown(e);

          }

        });




      slider.element.on("slide.selectPip slidechange.selectPip", function(e, ui) {

        var $slider = $(this),
          value = $slider.slider("value"),
          values = $slider.slider("values");

        if (ui) {

          value = ui.value;
          values = ui.values;

        }

        if (slider.values() && slider.values().length) {

          selectPip.range(values);

        } else {

          selectPip.single(value);

        }

      });




    },








    // floats

    float: function(settings) {

      var i,
        slider = this,
        min = slider._valueMin(),
        max = slider._valueMax(),
        value = slider._value(),
        values = slider._values(),
        tipValues = [],
        $handles = slider.element.find(".ui-slider-handle");

      var options = {

        handle: true,
        /* false */

        pips: false,
        /* true */

        labels: false,
        /* [array], { first: "string", rest: [array], last: "string" }, false */

        prefix: "",
        /* "", string */

        suffix: "",
        /* "", string */

        event: "slidechange slide",
        /* "slidechange", "slide", "slidechange slide" */

        formatLabel: function(value) {
          return this.prefix + value + this.suffix;
        }
        /* function
            must return a value to display in the floats */

      };

      if ($.type(settings) === "object" || $.type(settings) === "undefined") {

        $.extend(options, settings);
        slider.element.data("float-options", options);

      } else {

        if (settings === "destroy") {

          destroy();

        } else if (settings === "refresh") {

          slider.element.slider("float", slider.element.data("float-options"));

        }

        return;

      }




      if (value < min) {
        value = min;
      }

      if (value > max) {
        value = max;
      }

      if (values && values.length) {

        for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

          if (values[i] < min) {
            values[i] = min;
          }

          if (values[i] > max) {
            values[i] = max;
          }

        }

      }

      // add a class for the CSS
      slider.element
        .addClass("ui-slider-float")
        .find(".ui-slider-tip, .ui-slider-tip-label")
        .remove();



      function destroy() {

        slider.element
          .off(".sliderFloat")
          .removeClass("ui-slider-float")
          .find(".ui-slider-tip, .ui-slider-tip-label")
          .remove();

      }


      function getPipLabels(values) {

        // when checking the array we need to divide
        // by the step option, so we store those values here.

        var vals = [],
          steppedVals = $.map(values, function(v) {
            return Math.ceil((v - min) / slider.options.step);
          });

        // now we just get the values we need to return
        // by looping through the values array and assigning the
        // label if it exists.

        if ($.type(options.labels) === "array") {

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            vals[i] = options.labels[steppedVals[i]] || values[i];

          }

        } else if ($.type(options.labels) === "object") {

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            if (values[i] === min) {

              vals[i] = options.labels.first || min;

            } else if (values[i] === max) {

              vals[i] = options.labels.last || max;

            } else if ($.type(options.labels.rest) === "array") {

              vals[i] = options.labels.rest[steppedVals[i] - 1] || values[i];

            } else {

              vals[i] = values[i];

            }

          }

        } else {

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            vals[i] = values[i];

          }

        }

        return vals;

      }

      // apply handle tip if settings allows.
      if (options.handle) {

        // we need to set the human-readable label to either the
        // corresponding element in the array, or the appropriate
        // item in the object... or an empty string.

        tipValues = (slider.values() && slider.values().length) ?
          getPipLabels(values) :
          getPipLabels([value]);

        for (i = 0; i < tipValues.length; i++) {

          $handles
            .eq(i)
            .append($("<span class=\"ui-slider-tip\">" + options.formatLabel(tipValues[i]) + "</span>"));

        }

      }

      if (options.pips) {

        // if this slider also has pip-labels, we make those into tips, too.
        slider.element.find(".ui-slider-label").each(function(k, v) {

          var $this = $(v),
            val = [$this.data("value")],
            label,
            $tip;


          label = options.formatLabel(getPipLabels(val)[0]);

          // create a tip element
          $tip =
            $("<span class=\"ui-slider-tip-label\">" + label + "</span>")
            .insertAfter($this);

        });

      }

      // check that the event option is actually valid against our
      // own list of the slider's events.
      if (options.event !== "slide" &&
        options.event !== "slidechange" &&
        options.event !== "slide slidechange" &&
        options.event !== "slidechange slide") {

        options.event = "slidechange slide";

      }

      // when slider changes, update handle tip label.
      slider.element
        .off(".sliderFloat")
        .on(options.event + ".sliderFloat", function(e, ui) {

          var uiValue = ($.type(ui.value) === "array") ? ui.value : [ui.value],
            val = options.formatLabel(getPipLabels(uiValue)[0]);

          $(ui.handle)
            .find(".ui-slider-tip")
            .html(val);

        });

    }

  };

  $.extend(true, $.ui.slider.prototype, extensionMethods);

})(jQuery);


$(function() {
  $(".slider")
    .slider({
      max: 12,
      change: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.value);
      }
    })
    .slider("pips", {
      rest: "label"
    });
});
```

```css
#sliderScaleDiv {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#halo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.fluid {
  display: table-cell;
}

.slider {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 25px 10px;
}

#skull {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/dist/css/jquery-ui-slider-pips.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="sliderScaleDiv">
  <div id="halo">
    <img width="75" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/c/1/B/r/q/angel-halo-with-wings.svg" alt="Angel halo" />
  </div>

  <div class="fluid">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="skull">
    <img width="75" src="https://temporarytattoos.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x560/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/s/k/skull-and-crossbones-temporary-tattoos_1601.jpg" alt="Skull" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you're hard-coding 700px for the total width of everything but I'm not guaranteed taht every user visiting my site will have that screen real estate.  Can we just specify 100% instead of fixed widths?

Comment: that was just for an example you can change to 100% too i have updated in the example thou. @Natalia

Comment: Thanks, although I noticed you specified "width: 65%;" for the slider DIV.  Is there a way to tell it to take up as much space as possible?  "65%" seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: Yes you can use `display:table` for parent container and `display:table-cell` for the children see i updated the example @Natalia

Comment: Thanks for all the extra time, Muhammad.  It works brilliantly!

Comment: :) glad that i could help you out

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width for the slider.

```
.slider{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 65%;
}

#halo {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#skull {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

In the html I only set the height of the first image to match the 2nd image height so they align correctly.

```
<div id="sliderScaleDiv">
  <div id="halo">
     <img width="75" height="75" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/c/1/B/r/q/angel-halo-with-wings.svg" alt="Angel halo" />
 </div>
 <div class="slider"></div>
 <div id="skull">
  <img width="75" src="https://temporarytattoos.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x560/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/s/k/skull-and-crossbones-temporary-tattoos_1601.jpg" alt="Skull" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u72596ta/5/

Comment: Can I do this without explicitly setting a width for the slider?  IOW, can I make the slider take up all of the rest of the space that the iamges don't occupy?

Comment: You will need to define a width somewhere  in order for it to fit in the space you want. With css and media queries you can make it more responsive.